# Index seek with high cost (90%) and advise on NCI

Tags: sql, database, azure

I have one of the query where fact table is getting joined with dimension table on date fields (not datekeys) and this join is made using >= & <= between fields of fact and dimension. I saw query plan and this is taking 2.5 minutes to execute and index seek on fact showing cost of 90%. FYI, NCI created on fact is basically covering most of the columns (20+) in its definition.
Please advise whether this index is correct or what should be a good strategy to create indexes involving such joins in fact and dim

Comment: Without an example of the query and knowing the full index structures of the tables, your question is too broad.

Comment: _Please advise whether this index is correct_ Is it being used? If it is not being used then it's definitely incorrect. If it _is_ being used it's probably still incorrect if it contains that many columns. 90% is not necessarily a bad thing. It might just mean that there isn't much other work to do.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. Fact index is NCI and created on those 2 date fields joining with dimension and included all other fact columns in it. Similarly, NCI created on dimension for 2 date fields. I hope it should help.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid. Yeah it is being used. If I go without this index then plan shows table spool for this fact. Is that good?

Comment: If it's being used that's good. But if you could create a much smaller index (i.e. just the join columns) and it was still used, then is better certainly for this workload because the index is smaller = less I/O = faster. You're amost always better off creating many smaller indexes for specific purposes than creating a great big index with many columns. But never change indexes without measuring before and after performance.